# What is this town in Macedonia, Greece?

Tags: palaeography, historical-gazetteer, place-names, greece

I have been indexing on a FamilySearch (US Oregon Draft Registration WWII, this particular record was registered in 1942) and have come across a place name in Macadonia, Greece that I can find no where on the internet and I am not sure what the last two letters are. [image]

It looks like ‘Brazneeto’ or ‘Brazneetio’ but I cannot find anything to that affect anywhere on the internet. It could be that the name has been changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not an expert on Macedonian place names or history but from

> [Macedonian Village Names](http://macedonianhistory.ca/PDF/Macedonian%20village%20names.pdf)
>
> THE NAMES OF 804 MACEDONIAN VILLAGES IN AEGEAN MACEDONIA, occupied by
>   Greece in 1912, that have forcedly been changed from 1926 and forward.
>
> Submitted by Lena Jankovski and Alex Bakratcheff

I wonder whether it may be:

```
MACEDONIAN NAME (District) Greek changed name
Breznitza       (Kostur)   Vatohorion
```